# Saving map data in a 2d ORPG

Tags: c#, python, c++

I'm trying to figure out how I can best save the map data for a 2d ORPG engine I am developing, the file would contain tile data (Is it blocked, what actual graphics would it use, and various other properties).

I am currently using a binary format but I think this might be a bit too limited and hard to debug, what alternatives are there, I was thinking about perhaps JSON or XML but I don't know if there are any other better options.

It has to work with C++ and C# and preferably also with Python.

Comment: A few questions:
Why is binary difficult to debug?  
What kind of map sizes are you talking about?
Is there a reason you want to edit these by hand?

Comment: XML is well-supported and simple (no problems writing it or parsing it in C#, C++ or Python).

Comment: @Moo-Juice The map sizes are currently 30x20 tiles with 7 layers of tiles, and currently we don't have a map editor yet so that's why it would be easier to edit them by hand. So yeah hand-editing is a bit of an invalid argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would stick with a binary format.  Whatever method you choose, it's going to be a pain in the ass to edit by hand anyway, so you may as well stick to binary which gives you a size and speed advantage.

You're also going to want a map editor anyway so that you do not have to edit it by hand.

Comment: That is indeed good reasoning, however what about things such as a door that requires a key (Would need to store key ID in map), should I save that separately from the actual map data ?

Comment: Personally, I would store the "world" in it's own single file.  This would contain the map data (tiles, etc) and then the objects themselves (including where they are, what container they are in, etc, etc).  An interesting thing to note at this point is that the user's save-game/progress will override these.  When the user picks up the key, for example, the keys container is now different from where it was in the initial world.  This is not a complicated problem, however.  The state of the objects in the save-game file effectively override that of the initial world.

Comment: Following on from that, ensure that your code CAN save the state independently of the map as this will form the basis for your save-game data.  I guess it's apples & oranges as to whether the state is with the map data initially.  After some reflection, perhaps it's own file is the best way.

Comment: Well ORPG might've been the wrong term as it will actually be multiplayer, but what I came up with is using binary map files with some basic things such as blocked tiles and layer data. And then save doors, etc as entities in the database.

Comment: Yup, that makes perfect sense for what you're doing!

Answer (score 1):

XML is well supported across basically every language. It may become verbose for large maps, however, depending on how you encode the map data in XML.

JSON might not be  a good choice, simply because I don't think it supports multiline strings, which would be helpful (although not really necessary)

YAML is another alternative, though it's not as well-known.

You could just stick to binary - most maps would be a pain to edit by hand, no matter what format you pick (though I've heard of Starcraft maps being edited with hex editors...) Just use whatever seems easiest for you.

Additionally, check out the Tiled map editor (http://www.mapeditor.org/), which lets you edit maps (with custom tile properties, I think) and save it in an XML based format, including optional GZip for compression.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't require multiline strings, and I think json does support them though. Also I've used YAML before and it might be interesting to use

Answer (score 0):

Lua is also a possibility which can be used as a config file with [tables](http://www.lua.org/pil/12.html).  It's been a while since I worked with Python but doesn't it also support a AJAX style data structure?  You could simply use Python files if you are already using it.

Comment: "It has to work with C++ and C#, and preferably also python". and AJAX style data structures would be JSON I think. And I rather not use a programming language-esque thing to save the data in.